# TypeORM cant generate migrations

Tags: database, react-native, sqlite, orm, typeorm

i'm using typeORM as my ORM on an application built with react native, expo and sqlite. Today i'm using the attribute syncronize as true on my typeorm datasource, but I know that is not recommended to be used in produciton stages. So i'm trying to generate migrations to solve this error but i'm with an error.

I'm trying to run the following command to generate the migrations:

`typeorm migration:generate ./src/database/migrations/ -d ./data-source.js`

He recognize my datasource file but returns me the following error:

```
Error during migration generation:
Error: Unable to open file: "C:\<path>\data-source.js". Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

My dataSource are like this, but has more entities:

```
import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite';
import {DataSource} from "typeorm";
import Entity from './src/database/entities/Entity'

const dataSource = new DataSource({
    database: "dbname",
    driver: SQLite,
    entities: [
        Entity,
    ],
    synchronize: true,
    type: "expo",
});

export default dataSource
```

PS: I'm using javascript, not types

Already tried to module.exports this files but got more errors. I prefer to use import, not require.